# What could be expressed by "Ja, klar" in different situations?

Tags: meaning, expression

If I say "Ja klar", What are the different meanings expressed by this expression?

Comment: Depending on context and tone this can mean everything from "I agree and understand" over "I know and don't care" to "I don't believe you"...

Comment: exactly, I would like to understand it's meaning assuming different contexts and mood of person. Can you please elaborate it and add it as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that there are three main meanings for this expression.

1. First and more literal one is one you want to say that you agree with what the other people just said.
2. When you want to say that what the other people said is obvious and unnecessary.
3. In a sarcastic way when you want to say what the other people said is just no sense.

Answer (score 5):

The meanings are quite the same as of its verbatim translation

> Yes, of course.

As in English, it depends on the context if it should be interpreted literally or ironic. And as in English, if you hear this answer, there are situations where you can't be shure if it is meant literally or ironic.

Comment: Ja, klar. <!-- mehr als 10 Zeichen Gymnastik -->

Answer (score 0):

It means "But of course..." and then the speaker says more on the subject. It is usually in response to a question requiring a confirmation.

Comment: First of all, *But of course* isn't necessarily followed by any further context. Secondly, this expression - afaik - doesn't have any additional negative expression as *Ja, klar*, thus I consider *But of course* equally to the German *Aber natürlich* or *Aber selbstverständlich*. But of course it can also be used to introduce any obvious opposite as in this sentence.