# What is it, if not arrogance, that makes some germans answer many yes-or-no questions with "of course" (ja, klar)?

Tags: difference, culture

I know this is more a question about behaviour and cultural differences rather than about the german language but I still hope that it fits into this forum. If not please let me know and I will have my question removed.

In

[What could be expressed by "Ja, klar" in different situations?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5256/what-could-be-expressed-by-ja-klar-in-different-situations)

the accepted answer is:

> I think that there are three main meanings for this expression.
>
> 1. First and more literal one is one you want to say that you agree with what the other people just said.
> 2. When you want to say that what the other people said is obvious and unnecessary.
> 3. In a sarcastic way when you want to say what the other people said is just no sense.

I have been living in Germany for almost 15 years and even after all these years this still bothers me a lot because they often look stunned when saying it and even do not add anything to that answer. Even if the question asked was not trivial at all. This makes them appear to be very arrogant although I know they aren't (many germans I love and know very well do it).

Thank you very much in advance for any good hint.

Comment: VTC as opinion based (although should have been "needs more focus"). This is a pretty broad question which can not be answered here. We'd need more context to venture a guess. But even then, without knowing the person, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Just for your interest: Stack Exchange sites are not forums but Q&A sites. Such sites are inherently not meant for discussion. Or in other words: Everything that has no "correct answer" is not meant to be asked here.

Comment: I think the way "Ja, klar." appears is very dependent on the context and the tone. It definitely can sound very arrogant. It can also sound very normal and express agreement. In general I would suggest you to not add color where no color is.

Comment: I agree with @akuzminykh on this. The notion that "Ja klar" means it was unnecessary seems to go too far to me. "Ja, klar" from someone can also show strong support for your opinion or proposal.

Comment: Please notice that although "Ja, klar" is exactly a litteral translation, it doesn't carry the same connotation as portuguese/spanish "claro", which is very often used with a negative connotation.

Comment: I think this is really a cultural issue. Some Germans find it annoying when people from other cultures ask "Wie geht's ?" each time they meet them. They know that they are not really asked for a report about how well they are doing and that they are asked this question simply out of politness but they find it annoying when they are asked such a question when actually no honest answer is expected.

Comment: I cannot remember at the moment, but I know a derivation from PIE that would be largely unrelated to *clearly*. The fact that *na-klar* is fossilized and that *na-* is unambiguously not a word of it's own (but cognate to *nu-*, *nun*, *nunja*, *naja* I'm sure, naja klar) means it is certainly not a recent invention. *Alles klärchen*?

Comment: You would provide examples of what you ask in which context for us to understand what the other person means when they say "Ja, klar". If, as you say, the other person is commonly stunned by your question, then you seem to be asking what the other person sees as unnecessary questions. If you don't find the questions unnecessary, your best approach would be to ask the person why they don't react in the way you expected. **Communication is the key to most interpersonal problems.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it can be seen as quite the opposite, i.e.  as an attempt, **not** to be rude. To answer simply   with *yes* or *no* is in both cases mono-syllabic. (Even more so in case of several subsequent questions.)

While I have currently no educational source at hand, I remember *oh ja, gerne* or *ja, da hätte ich Lust dazu* to be the kind of answer considered as more acceptable when I was a child. I admit, that *ja, klar* is not convincingly better than a simple *ja*, but at least it remains quite context-independent and therefore universal.